# SwiftUI tap picker like a button

Tags: swiftui

Is it possible to make a SwiftUI picker tap like a button. The following only lets you set the picker if you tap on the text, but I would like to tap the picker like a button.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var myvar: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: $myvar, label:
            Text("Phone Type")) {
            Text("Home").tag(0)
            Text("Service").tag(1)
            Text("Work").tag(2)
            Text("Cell").tag(3)
            Text("Other").tag(4)
        }.padding().border(Color.gray)
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Look at `Menu` (if needed with explicit .button style)

Comment: Thanks!! Yeah I was able to use the `label` element on the `Menu` to make button like text to click. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Asperi was right in their comment. The `Menu` is better than the `picker` when wanting it to display as a button. Here is a simple code example.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var myvar: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        Menu {
            // This should be done in a ForEach loop
            Button("Home", action: {myvar="Home"})
            Button("Service", action: {myvar="Service"})
            Button("Work", action: {myvar="Work"})
            Button("Cell", action: {myvar="Cell"})
            Button("Other", action: {myvar="Other"})
        } label: {
            //THIS ALLOWS CLICKING TO OPEN ON THE BLUE BACKGROUND
            Text("ClickHere")
                .frame(width: 200, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try this with `.pickerStyle`. Note that your `tag(...)` needs to match the type in `myvar`, so using string, like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var myvar: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: $myvar, label: Text("Phone Type")) {
            Text("Home").tag("Home")
            Text("Service").tag("Service")
            Text("Work").tag("Work")
            Text("Cell").tag("Cell")
            Text("Other").tag("Other")
        }
        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        .padding().border(Color.gray)
    }
}
```